# How to get rid of hideous spacing before the year in the pub list of my CV?

Tags: spacing, natbib, cv, revtex, bibunits

Each entry in the Publications sections looks fine until the separation between title and year, when I get this eyeball-gougingly ugly three-space separation between publication title and year; *e.g.*,

`J.D. Salinger, The Catcher in the Rye,   (1951).`

The parenthetical year is made into a hyperlink, and removing that link doesn't help.  (I also really dislike the comma after the title and the parentheses enclosing the year, but I'll settle for them if changing them is more trouble than it's worth.)

Note that the code is on Overleaf, not my local machine.

Here is the .bib:

```
@CONTROL{REVTEX42Control}
@CONTROL{apsrev42Control,author="00",pages="1",title="0",year="0"}

@article{Hohertz_Factors_2020,
author = {Hohertz, Matt},
title = {Bounds for the zeros of {C}ollatz polynomials, with necessary and sufficient strictness conditions},
url = {https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.08006.pdf},
year = {2020}
}
```

and the .tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%% Define some new colors
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mBlue}{RGB}{51, 77, 167}
\newcommand{\blue}[1]{{\color{mBlue}#1}}

%% Page and text formatting
\usepackage[left=1.0in, right=1.0in, top=1.0in, bottom=1.0in]{geometry} % margins
\usepackage{setspace}
\singlespacing % No more than 6 lines of text per inch
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

%% Make the sections start with (a), (b), etc.
\renewcommand\thesection{(\alph{section})}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{(\alph{subsection})}

%% Set up footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{CVfooter}
{
 \lhead{}
 \chead{}
 \rhead{}
 \lfoot{\small{Matt Hohertz}}
 \cfoot{\small{\today}}
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
 \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
}

%% Set up hyperlinks
\usepackage[linktoc=page]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks = true,
  urlcolor = mBlue,
  citecolor = mBlue,
  linkcolor = mBlue,
}

%% Set up citations and bibliography
\usepackage{bibunits}
\usepackage[sort&compress,super]{natbib}
\defaultbibliographystyle{apsrev4-2}
\setcitestyle{comma}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{\ \ \ #1.}
\renewcommand\refname{\vspace{-7mm}}

%% This allows us to start a bibliography with arbitrary number
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\newbibstartnumber}[1]{%
  \apptocmd{\thebibliography}{%
    \global\c@NAT@ctr #1\relax
    \addtocounter{NAT@ctr}{-1}%
  }{}{}%
}
\makeatother

%% Reduce whitespace around lists (globally)
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,left=0pt}
\setlist[enumerate]{nosep}
\setlist[description]{nosep}

%% Formatting for sections
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0mm}{2mm}{1mm}[0mm] % left top bottom right
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0mm}{2mm}{1mm}[0mm]
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries\itshape}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0mm}{1mm}{0mm}[0mm]

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{CVfooter}

\section{Research Experience}

\vspace{1mm}
\noindent \textbf{\textit{\ \ Author or co-author}}

\begin{bibunit}
\nocite{apsrev42Control}
\nocite{Hohertz_Collatz_2020, Hohertz_Factors_2020, Hohertz2020, HohertzKalantari2020}
\putbib[publications]
\end{bibunit}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! Unfortunately I don't see the problem because 1) I don't know the name of your bib file, and 2) much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: @erik, I'm confused.  You just told me to post a "complete compilable document," yet now object that most of the code is irrelevant.  Could you please clarify what you want me to do?  The tex file is called main.tex, and the bib file is publications.bib.

Comment: The best approach is to post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. This means you should include `\documentclass{...}`, the *required* `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. However, to keep it minimal, you should omit whatever is unrelated to the problem, which is most of your CV in this case (except the `bibunit`s). If I use what you posted I don't see any citations at all (since you use `\nocite`), so the spacing issue you mention is not reproduced and therefore extremely difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: @erik Ah, got it.  Thanks. 
I also think there may be a misunderstanding [on which end, I don't know! ;)].  I am not, e.g., inline citing within a published article; rather, I'm listing my own articles.  \nocite seems like an odd choice, but it's what the template used.  Though maybe I should try something different?  (Stay tuned: I'm going to edit my code to satisfy your request.)

Comment: @erik Ok, I've cut out as much as possible to make a MWE.

Comment: @matty_k_walrus: When specifying an `@article` entry, you need to provide the following details with that entry: `journal`, `volume` and `pages`. Without those, they contribute to the spaces.